# Python how do I get an integer after a specific string in a paragraph?

Tags: python, search

I have large paragraphs of text, and if it contains "I lost" I want to get the numbers right after that. Here's what I have:

```
word = ['i lost']
if isMatch
    print(re.findall('\d+', comment_text)[0])
```

This returns the first number in the paragraph, but that usually isn't the number after 'I lost'. How do I get those numbers only if it is after that string?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
>>> re.findall('i lost(\d+)', comment_text)
```

Returns a list of possible matches of string of integers right after the string "i lost".

Comment: Oh alright. So this is saying that in c, it'll find the integer after 'i lost'?

Comment: I didn't quite caught you, is it not what you were looking for??

Comment: Yes that's the goal! I was making sure I understood, so I wouldn't have this problem again. Thank you

Comment: Welcome buddy... Could you please do me favour and tag the answer as selected, then?

Comment: Yes, it says I have to wait five minutes, but I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'i\s+lost\s*([\d.,]+)', comment_text, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
else:
    print("Number was not found")
```

I didn't know if the number is going to be a float or an integer, so this will catch both. If this is only an integer, you can change the ([\d,.]+) to (\d+).